# What causes Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently doing some research about that issue that was shown from firebase crashlytics. And I can't seem to identify the origin of the issue. What exactly is causing this issue? Also, this issue mainly only comes from Android 10. Any help is appreciated.

line 114:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

from

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvLeadImg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Error log:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115 in com.knx.thestarmobile:layout/fragment_activity_article: Binary XML file line #115 in com.knx.thestarmobile:layout/fragment_activity_article: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

There are also some additional stack traces such as:

```
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115 in com.knx.thestarmobile:layout/fragment_activity_article: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

and

```
Caused by com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver$TimeoutException: Interrupted
   at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.waitResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:60)
   at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.getIntResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:68)
   at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:1841)
   at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.isEnabled(AutofillManager.java:830)
   at Al.<init>(Al.java:4)
   at El.<init>(El.java:1)
   at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:19)
   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.a(WebViewChromium.java:8)
   at N3.run(N3.java:1)
   at bp.a(bp.java:6)
   at Zo.run(Zo.java:1)
   at org.chromium.base.task.PostTask.a(PostTask.java:14)
   at bp.a(bp.java:3)
   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:72)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:429)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:353)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:336)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:323)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:776)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
   at com.knx.thestarmobile.ui.news.common.ArticleFragment.onCreateView(ArticleFragment.java:247)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:434)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:259)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7231)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:743)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7231)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7231)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7231)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1003)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26367)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3551)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2300)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2592)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2148)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8831)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:996)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:729)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

These are the stack traces found from the crashlytics. Any solutions for these errors? What is causing all these errors?

**UPDATE**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(!RealmHelper.NightmodeHelper.isNightMode(getContext()) ? R.layout.fragment_activity_article : R.layout.fragment_activity_article_nightmode, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        String articleID = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(ARTICLE_ID) : ARTICLE_ID;
        String catId = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(CAT_ID) : CAT_ID;
        hasMoreStory = getArguments() != null && getArguments().getBoolean(HAS_MORE_STORY);
        isNotf = getArguments() != null && getArguments().getBoolean(IS_NOTF);
        isTwoPane = getArguments() != null && getArguments().getBoolean(IS_TWOPANE);

        isTriggerRefresh = false;

        appBarLayout.setVisibility(isTwoPane ? GONE : VISIBLE);
        sdFab.setVisibility(isTwoPane ? VISIBLE : GONE);
        if (isTwoPane) setupSdFab();

        new ArticlePresenter(this, getContext(), articleID, catId, isTwoPane);
        mPresenter.start();

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: What is in your `ArticleFragment.onCreateView(ArticleFragment.java:247)` ?

Comment: I updated the method to the bottom part of the question. Line 247 appears to be a blank space in between "if (isTwoPane) setupSdFab();" and "new ArticlePresenter(this, getContext(), articleID, catId, isTwoPane);"

Comment: did you test it to set android:layout_width="0dp" to android:layout_width="wrap_content"?

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue on our devices, this issue is only reported by crashlytics. @Mr.AF

Comment: @Mr.AF Any suggestions on how to reproduce the error or resolve the issue above?

Comment: Any solutions from anyone is welcomed.

Comment: Please help. This issue is piling up. I have multiple users with Android 10 (Huawei and Samsung) complaining on crash, but I couldn't find the problem. Currently this crash is the top crashes found in Firebase.